# Site Features in Sub Webs Confusion

Tags: 2007, development, feature, migration, site-collection

Very Basic but confusing question.

I see we have three types of features,

- Web Application Features
- Site Collection Features
- Site Features

Now I know that Web application features belong to web application and can be accessed through Central Admin, and Site Collection Features belong to a site collection.

**However am bit confused with Site Features, Like I have hundred of sites/web/subwebs in a site Collection, will each site will have same "Site Features" or they can vary depending on site/webs**

Why am confused ?

Because I have to export a Site to a New Site Collection, So programmatically I want to go through Each feature that is activated in Site (old exported site) to new Site Collection(Imported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web scoped feature will be associated with a single website.

It is therefore possible that only a subset of websites in a site collection will have a certain web scoped feature and the others will not.